# What happens when a Python yield statement has no expression?

Tags: python, generator, yield

I'm a C# programmer trying to understand some Python code. The code in question is a generator function, and looks like this:

```
def func():
    oldValue = curValue
    yield
    curValue = oldValue
```

If I understand this correctly, this will generate a iterable sequence with one member. However, there is no expression after the `yield` statement. What is such an expression-less statement supposed to yield? Are there any Python idioms that make use of this way of coding?

Comment: Same as: `yield None`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It'll yield `None`; just like an empty `return` expression would:

```
>>> def func():
...     yield
... 
>>> f = func()
>>> next(f) is None
True
```

You'd use it to *pause code*. Everything before the `yield` is run when you first call `next()` on the generator, everything after the `yield` is only run when you call `next()` on it again:

```
>>> def func():
...     print("Run this first for a while")
...     yield
...     print("Run this last, but only when we want it to")
... 
>>> f = func()
>>> next(f, None)
Run this first for a while
>>> next(f, None)
Run this last, but only when we want it to
```

I used the two-argument form of `next()` to ignore the `StopIteration` exception thrown. The above doesn't care what is `yield`ed, only that the function is paused at that point.

For a practical example, the [`@contextlib.contextmanager` decorator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) fully expects you to use `yield` in this manner; you can *optionally* `yield` an object to use in the `with ... as` target. The point is that everything before the `yield` is run when the context is entered, everything after is run when the context is exited.

Comment: I have so much to learn in python :) Parasite question: Can we implement some sort of check-point system using multiple empty `yield`s? Or is this dangerous?

Comment: You can look at slides here: http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/index.html Short answer: yield is very powerful.

Comment: @x3al: sure, but as `yield` is used here as a statement rather than as an expression (the expression result is ignored) we are not quite in coroutine country just yet. :-)

Comment: Still, the idea of using `yield` as a `goto` on steroids is similar to coroutine "threads".

Comment: @x3al: I'm sorry but I'm a bit lost... Are you guys commenting on my question? (I think you are, but not I'm sure :) )

Comment: I know this is a late comment, but… I just looked at the yield docs (due to some post on Reddit) and I really don't see where yield can have no expression.  The syntax, as in the docs, doesn't allow it.  Or what am I missing?